# CRTP - Keeping implementation hidden from public

Tags: c++, crtp

I'm using Curiously Recurring Template Pattern for creating classes which have common interface, but specific implementation.

Most of CRTP examples I found on web use `struct`, so the code which uses them may call the `implementation()` directly instead of the `interface()`.

Someone proposed to put `implementation()` into Derived's private section and add `friend Base`. However this seems to me somehow inelegant.

I was trying to find a solution to keep the `implementation()` hidden from public. Here's the solution, it uses inner `Proxy` class inside `Base`.

```
template<class T> class Base
{
public:
    void interface()
    {
        return static_cast<Proxy*>(this)->implementation();
    }

private:
    class Proxy: public T
    {
        // friend Base; /* uncomment to allow full access */
        friend void Base::interface();
    };
};

class Derived: public Base<Derived>
{
protected:
    void implementation()
    {

    }
};
```

Now code using Derived will be forced to call `interface()`, since `implementation()` is protected.

I'd like to discuss here possible pitfails of the solution.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, since `*this` is not a `Proxy`.

Comment: I think you're trying to implement a kind of PIMPL. In that case, your `Base` class needs to own a pointer to a `Proxy`, and then in your `interface` function, you call `implementation` on your pointer.

Comment: Agreed it's an undefined behaviour -> will revert the wiki article.

Comment: As well as UB, this makes no sense. What is "somehow inelegant"? Did you simply want to avoid repetition of `friend` decls in derived classes? Anyway, I don't understand your objections. To make "hidden from public" is to make non-`public`, which the proper idiom does, with only minimal additions in derived classes, while actually producing valid code. And making `private` is better than your `protected` here.